# initialize typescript object with falsy default values

Tags: typescript, interface

I have the following interface

```
interface I {
  age:number
  name:string
  list:string[]
}
```

I wanto know if there is a easy way to initalize an object of this type with default falsy values like in Golang.  I want:

```
let obj: I
console.log(obj)
```

to print:

```
{age:0,name:'',list:[]}
```

instead of

```
{}
```

Comment: Interfaces do not exist at runtime. They are only there to make sure your code is correct at compile time. So, this cannot be done as just an interface. You can use a class with a default constructor, perhaps.

Comment: can you show me what you mean?